# Summing numpy array blockwise to form a smaller array

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

We have a matrix N x N consisting of n x n blocks. So we have (N/n) x (N/n) blocks. We further divide it into large blocks so that each large block contains m x m number of smaller blocks. And then we need to sum (block-wise) smaller blocks inside each larger block. For example here each A is nxn and m = 2.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QClXA.gif)

**What is the simplest and possibly fast way of doing that with `numpy` array?**

Comment: Is it that `N / m = n`, where `m` is the number of blocks and `n` is the block size?

Comment: No. N is matrix size. n is block size. m is completely differenet. we need to add blockwise.

Comment: In our case, N/n is some multiple of m.

Comment: Could you make same example? Right now I do not see how `N` is not divisible by `n` without introducing imperfect blocking.

Comment: And this is not a duplicate of the above question. There you just add entries inside a block. Here it is block of blocks.

Comment: I dont say that N is not divisible by n, of course it is. But what is the relation to m.

Comment: Oh I see. Then you would need to do a slicing on the `m` dimension before the `sum`. You should really provide some example, otherwise this is just guesswork on the reader side.

Answer (score 1):

One fast way of doing this is to reshape your `(N, N)` array into `(m, n, m, n)` and then sum along the axes of size `m`:

```
import numpy as np

m = 3
n = 2
N = m * n

arr = np.arange((N * N)).reshape((N, N))
print(arr)
# [[ 0  1  2  3  4  5]
#  [ 6  7  8  9 10 11]
#  [12 13 14 15 16 17]
#  [18 19 20 21 22 23]
#  [24 25 26 27 28 29]
#  [30 31 32 33 34 35]]

reshaped = arr.reshape((m, n, m, n))
summed = np.sum(reshaped, axis=(0, 2))

print(summed)
# [[126 135]
#  [180 189]]


# ...checking a couple of blocks
# the "first m" (index 0) identifies blocks along rows
# the "second m" (index 2) identifies blocks along columns
print(reshaped[0, :, 0, :])
# [[0 1]
#  [6 7]]
print(reshaped[1, :, 2, :])
# [[16 17]
#  [22 23]]

# ...manually checking that the (0, 0) element of `summed` is correct
sum([0, 2, 4, 12, 14, 16, 24, 26, 28])
# 126
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I think it is for single entries, but I need blockwise addition. It is kind of a block of blocks.